# C# memcpy equivalent

Tags: c#, serialization, copying

I have 2 objects from the same type and i would like to shallow copy one state to the other. In C++ i have memcpy which is great. How can i do it in C#? The MemberwiseClone() is not good enough because it creates & returns a new object and i like to copy to an existing object. I thought of using reflection but i'm afraid it will be too slow for production code. I also thought of using one of the .Net serializers but i think they also create object rather than setting an existing one.

**My Use Case:**

I have a template object (class not struct) which needs to be updated by one of its instances (objects made of this template)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[edit] regarding your clarification:
As I understand, you have N objects, each has a (direct) reference to the template object. You want to write back to the template so all objects "see" these changes.

Suggestion: imlement a template broker.

```
class TemplateProvider
{
   public MyData Template { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of passing the template, pass the template provider to the objects.

to simplyfy the syntax in the components, you can add a (private/internal?) property

```
MyData Template { get { return m_templateProvider.Template; } }
void UpdateTemplate() { m_templateProvider.Template = 
                            (MyData) this.MemberwiseClone(); }
```

The template provider also simplifies locking in multithreaded scenarios.

---

In short, no way unless you do it yourself. But why not create a new object if you override all properties anyway?

`memcopy` and similar low level constructs are not supported since they undermine guarantees made by the environment.

A shallow copy for structs is made by assignment. For classes, `MemberwiseClone` is the method to do that - but as you say that creates a new object.

There is no built in way for that, and as it potentially breaks encapsulation it should be used with care anyway.

You could build a generic routine using reflection, but whether it works or not depends on the class itself. And yes, ti will be comparedly slow.

What's left is supporting it by a custom interface. You can provide a generic "Shallow Copy" routine that checks for the interface and uses that, and falls back to reflection when it doesn't. This makes the functionality available generally, and you can optimize the classes for which performance matters later.

Answer (score 5):

In `C#` (and in `C++` too), there is no difference between "new object" and "a copy of existing object" as long as all their members equal to each other.

Given:

```
Int32 a = 5;
```

, both operations:

```
Int32 b = 5;
Int32 b = a;
```

yield the same result.

As stated in [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx):

> The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object.
>
> If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed.
>
> If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

, i.e. it does just the same as `memcpy()` in `C++`

Answer (score 3):

C# / .Net memcpy equivalent is **Buffer.MemoryCopy** .

```
void MemoryCopy (void* source, void* destination, long destinationSizeInBytes, long sourceBytesToCopy);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.memorycopy?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just do something like:

```
YourObjectType A = new YourObjectType();
YourObjectType B = a.MemberwiseClone();
```

This will create a new object inside the MemberwiseClone method an make the B object reference it. I guess it serves your purposes.

Comment: He wants to know, how one can copy the contents of an object A *into* an existing object B, overriding all its contents. MemberwiseClone creates a *new* object.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment of one struct to another, for all intents and purposes, works *exactly* like `memcpy` in C++ on POD objects.

If you feel that this doesn't apply in your situation then I can assure you that your C++ code was not standard-conforming (i.e., contained bugs in the form of undefined behaviour). Please specify (*in the question*) what effect you want to achieve. This will be more useful than talking about replicating undefined behaviour in another language.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{

    [Serializable] // just put this in your class
    class Mate
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var mA = new Mate();
            mA.SomeProperty = "Hey";

            var vf = new BinaryFormatter();
            var ns = new MemoryStream();
            vf.Serialize(ns, mA);
            byte[] vytes = ns.ToArray();


            var vfx = new BinaryFormatter();
            var nsx = new MemoryStream();            
            nsx.Write(vytes, 0, vytes.Length);
            nsx.Seek(0, 0);
            var mB = (Mate)vfx.Deserialize(nsx);

            mA.SomeProperty = "Yo";

            MessageBox.Show(mA.SomeProperty); // Yo
            MessageBox.Show(mB.SomeProperty); // Hey
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("lastname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("firstname", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add("lennon", "john");
            dt.Rows.Add("mccartney", "paul");


            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, dt);
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();



            var bfx = new BinaryFormatter();
            var msx = new MemoryStream();
            msx.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            msx.Seek(0, 0);


            // doesn't just copy reference, copy all contents
            var dtx = (DataTable)bfx.Deserialize(msx);


            dtx.Rows[0]["lastname"] = "Ono";


            // just copy reference
            var dty = dt;

            dty.Rows[0]["lastname"] = "Winston";

            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString()); // Winston
            MessageBox.Show(dtx.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString()); // Ono
            MessageBox.Show(dty.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString()); // Winston

        }
    }
}
```