# memcpy function in c#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# memcpy equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510971/c-memcpy-equivalent)

What is the equivalent of the `memcpy` function in c#?

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Any details what you try to do. Because the approach will vary based on that.

Comment: Your question lacks way to much information to be answered. Since you're talking about memcpy I assume you want to copy using Pointers? But then there are multiple type of pointers in c#. So could you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually I have two applications, first in c# and 2nd in c++, both the applications are communicating with each other, for the encoding, I use memcpy function, which I have to decode in c# application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said it depends what you are trying to do...
So you can consider one of these... check the links:

- [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx)
- [Object.MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)
- [ICloneable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)

There may be other possible options based on your needs...

Answer (score 5):

[`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) is close, but limited to arrays.  I agree it depends what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

For copying (byte) arrays, you can use the Array.Copy() method, but that's probably not what you want:

```
byte[] array1 = new byte[10] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
byte[] array2 = new byte[10];

Array.Copy(array1,array2,10);
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `Buffer.BlockCopy`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is none. C# protects the actual memory behind several layers of abstraction. For some purposes, the `IClonable` interface may be of some help though.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact equivalent, but does [`Array::Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5s0whfd.aspx) do what you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unsafe` and pointers. But your particular case would say a bit more about what direction you should head.